# Why is charconv header missing in macosx Mojave 10.14 with gcc5?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++17, libc++

I am trying to do some very fast conversions in C++ and charconv seems the way to go since it uses a very low level logic. The problem is that when I try to include this header and then call, say, std::to_chars(...), neither the header is found nor std has a 'to_chars' member. I updated and reinstalled gcc but this problem is still there. Now I have seen some threads that say that I should update somehow libc++17 but they are not very specific about what I should do, as things are a bit different for MacOS.

Some code to illustrate the library and it's use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <charconv> //error: 'charconv' file not found

struct to_chars_result{
   char *str;
   std::errc err;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string str("12Test");

    auto result = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), 12345); //No
     //member named 'to_chars' in namespace 'std'.


    return 0;
}
```

As for gcc -v command output:

> COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>     COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.1.0/lto- 
>     wrapper
>     Ziel: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
>     Konfiguriert mit: ../gcc-5.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
>     Thread-Modell: posix
>     gcc-Version 5.1.0 (GCC)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you compiling with the GCC -std=c++17 option?

Comment: @Flau It doesn't really matter because it still gives the error regardless of the language version specification, so yes I am compiling w/ it.

Comment: @Flau Plus charconv is a recent library added to c++, I think in 2017, so I guess c++17 would be the logical choice if you want to use it. For more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/charconv

Comment: Yes, I was just checking incase you weren't using the flag. I haven't used the header before so it was just an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc 5.1 was released on April 22, 2015.

The paper that added `to_chars` to the C++17 standard was written in 2016.

Why do you expect that gcc5 will have implemented it?

[ Later: That was the paper that added the `<charconv>` header, too ]

Comment: Well I checked and apparently you are right, after building gcc 8.3 it works just fine! Thanks!